# Add another Firebase user to a group by their uid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am developing an app using React Native w/Redux and Firebase. I am trying to implement group user management where a user that is logged in can add another user to a group by their uid. However I cannot seem to retrieve another user by their uid.

A snapshot of the path `users/${enteredUid}` returns an empty object even if a correct `uid` is used. I also cannot retrieve a list of all users by getting a snapshot of `users/` as this also returns a blank object.

Does firebase not allow the authenticated user to see any data relating to other users? I cannot find a suitable solution to this online.

```
export const addUser = (enteredUid) => {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
  return (dispatch) => {
  let user = {};
  firebase.database().ref(`users/${enteredUid}`)
  .on('value', snapshot => {
    user = snapshot.val();
  });
  if (user !== undefined) {
    console.log(user);
    firebase.database().ref(`users/${currentUser.uid}/group/users`)
    .push(user)
    .then(() => {
      dispatch({ type: GM_SET_SUCCESS, payload: `User ${enteredUid.username} added successfuly!` });
    }
  );
} else {
  dispatch({ type: GM_SET_ERROR, payload: `User ${enteredUid} does not exist!` });
}
};
};
```

**Firebase Database Rules**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Database ScreenShot**

[Firebase ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvsFI.png)

Comment: move `console.log(user);` inside `.on()` method and check what it gives.

Comment: It turned out to be the firebase rules. Using the firebase console I was able to test s read on the path /users which failed until the rules were changed to allow read and write everywhere.